# How do I copy a const float* const to float*?

Tags: c++, c

So in my function, I was passed a parameter `const float* const d_inputArray`
How do I read its content and copy to a different array `float* d_tempInput`?
I don't know how do deal with either const.

Comment: `malloc` an array, `memcpy` the contents, then `free` when done.

Comment: What do you want do? If you are passed a `const float *`, it is because the calling code expects your function not to modify the values pointed by that parameter.

Comment: As @OliCharlesworth says. Treat like a regular array. It only means you can't modify it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming both pointers point to buffers of the same size:

`memcpy(d_tempInput, d_inputArray, LENGTH_OF_BUFFER_IN_BYTES);`

Comment: And make sure to `d_tempInput = malloc(LENGTH_OF_BUFFER_IN_BYTES)` first, and check the returned pointer!

Answer (score 0):

```
/* malloc memory for d_tempInput */
d_tempInput = (float *) malloc(sizeof(d_inputArray)); 

/* memcpy everything from d_inputArray into d_tempInput */
memcpy(d_tempInput, d_inputArray, sizeof(d_inputArray)); 

/* Free when done */
free(d_tempInput);
```

Answer (score 0):

## Example: const float * -> float * -> const float *

The keyword `const` refers to the content of the memory region the pointer points to.

Do not confuse this with a constant pointer (construction by `float * const pntr`). Read [Constant Pointers and Pointers to Constants](https://www.codeguru.com/cpp/cpp/cpp_mfc/general/article.php/c6967/Constant-Pointers-and-Pointers-to-Constants.htm) for more info.

**Code**

Interactive version: [here](https://techiedelight.com/compiler/?IFkQ)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

int main()
{
    size_t N = 3;
    
    const float a[N] = {100, 101, 102};
    
    //float *b = a;  // not possible
    float *b = new float[N];
    std::memcpy(b, a, N*sizeof(float));
    
    const float *c = b;
    
    for (size_t ii = 0; ii < N; ++ii)
    {
        std::cout << a[ii] << "; " << b[ii] << "; " << c[ii] << std::endl;
    }
    delete b;
    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
100; 100; 100
101; 101; 101
102; 102; 102
```